# Using HeaderDoc with .hpp files instead of .h files

Tags: c++, header-files, headerdoc

I want to document my interface. The interface is written in C++ and it is in .hpp files. However, `headerdoc2html` doesn't seem to know about .hpp files; it expects .h files.

> ```
> $ headerdoc2html include/*.hpp
> HTML output mode.
> File include/serializer.hpp is not of a known header or source code file type
> No valid input files specified. 
>
> Usage: headerdoc2html [-dq] [-o <output directory>] <input file(s) or directory>.
> ```

How can I force HeaderDoc to interpret the input as C++ code?

Comment: How about renaming the .hpp files to .h?

Comment: @Tibi epic incompatibility with existing users of the interface.

Comment: Okay, but you could create a temporary folder where you put all the .hpp files, rename them to .h, build the documentation, without modifying the original.

Comment: @WTP'--, you can just create symlinks to your `.hpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have a dirty suggestion: copy the .hpp files to .h files. You can do that in the makefile.

Here is a snippet of the Makefile

```
.SUFFIXES: .h .hpp
.hpp.h:
     cp $< $@
```

remember the tab in the Makefile, before the "cp"-line